# Psycopg2 and sqlalchemy both not working to pull data from a local PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm having a little trouble. I've tried using psycopg2 and sqlalchemy to get into my local PostgreSQL database and, while it's not throwing an error, it won't make the connection. Instead it's just stuck executing the code. Here's where it's going wrong.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='db', user="user", password="password", host="127.0.0.1", port="55212")
```

And likewise when using sqlalchemy here is where it's going wrong.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://pw:db@localhost:55212/DB')
```

Please help, I can't do anything until this is resolved!

Comment: It could be the server isn't active, or a firewall?  Why are you using different ports in each attempt?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question. I'm using the same port. Maybe if I connect to the VPN it will work. I'll try that now.

Comment: So I tried connecting to the VPN and that's not working either. I don't know if it's a firewall but that sounds promising. Can you help me figure out how to get around it so I can check if that is the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct port?  5432 is the default.

Comment: This is the url to get into pgadmin: http://127.0.0.1:55212/browser/

Comment: Try 5432.  You should be connecting to the Postgresql  server, not pgadmin.

Comment: Ok, it seems like that is working but I'm not able to pull any data. The line of code I am using is the following: `df = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM public."Vehtek_SLG"
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100""")`. Can you tell me why it's returning a NoneType object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the logs, one can only guess.
But basically, when using `sqlalchemy` your connection string that you pass to `create_engine` should look like: `"postgresql+psycopg2://user_name:password@host_address:port/schema"`.
If the data you passed is correct, make sure your DB server is open for connections.
If you are attempting to connect to a docker container from within a different docker container, make sure they share a network, and change `host_address` from localhost to the name of the container.

The default port for PostgreSQL is `5432` so make sure what port to use before trying a different one.
After creating the `Engine`, connect to the db with `engine.connect()`, which returns a connection (preferably with a context manager).

You can then use that connection to `execute` queries or pass it to pandas `read_sql_query` method.

Comment: It seems as though this has worked. Can you tell me why this sql query is not executing now? `df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM public.TestDataFlow_SLG LIMIT 1000",con=engine)` Do I need to specify a cursor? I don't know if it actually worked but it allowed me to create the engine...

Comment: First and foremost, please provide more information such as logs when asking, this would make it much easier to help you. Second - i'm not very familiar with pandas `read_sql_query`, but it seems the `con` argument is expecting a connection, not an engine (which is what `create_engine` returns). 
use `con = engine.connect()` and then pass that to `read_sql_query`.

Comment: Got it. I'll edit your answer and mark it as correct.